# find if background image is used for any html tag with inline style

Tags: python, html, parsing, xpath, lxml

How do I find all the tags which have a background image ?
No stylesheets used. All styling is inline in the tags.

I'm using **lxml** and xpath, currently. This is how far I could get:

```
from lxml import html  
html_text = """somehtml"""

doc = html.fromstring(html_text)  
tagWithBackgrounds = doc.xpath("//*[contains(@style,'background')]")
```

What next ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`doc.xpath('//*[contains(@style,"background") and contains(@style,"url(")]')`

not perfect, but works.

Answer (score 0):

According to [xmlme.com's XpathTool](http://www.xmlme.com/XpathTool.aspx) this xPath should work:

```
//*[contains(@style,'background-image')]
```

Here is my test result:

[image]

Comment: But one could use, `background` attribute to specify an image, not necessarily a `background-image`

Comment: Oh I see. I don't think you can do such pattern recognition with just Xpath. You should first fetch all nodes that contain the word `background` in their inline style, then iterate over them and confirm that their styles contain background images using regex.

Comment: yes, can't get a perfect answer to it. URL matching is itself a big challenge. But i made a xpath expression good enough for my purpose.